# Migrating from Magneto 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, data-migration-tool

I migrated all my settings, products etc from M1 to M2 recently.

Our old site has while developing our new M2 site gained new customers and products. So what would happen if I choose to migrate my data from M1 to M2 again?
As in this command: php bin/magento migrate:data --reset

Would the old products be overwritten and new products, customers be added or would it create duplicate products, customers and what not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want migrate all data or only order,customer data ... etc ???

Comment: Basically everything the command "migrate:data" migrates. so products, categories, orders, customers, wish lists etc. all that ?

Comment: yes all that migrate ...

Comment: No you misunderstand I think :) I want to migrate again. Will my data be duplicated or overwritten

Comment: you are migrate data data and i think data is exits error showing...

Comment: in my suggestion magento 1 migrate magento 2 fresh magento.after migrate your old developing site move to new migrate magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a 50% chance that you will have corrupted data if you do so. and re-migration will fail even in `-a` ignore mode, because of a lot of data changes.
duplicates and incompatible records.

what you need to do is `:delta`

> The incremental migration tool installs deltalog tables (with prefix
>   m2_cl_*) and triggers (for tracking changes) in the Magento 1 database
>   during the migration of data. These deltalog tables and triggers are
>   essential to ensuring that you migrate only the changes made in
>   Magento 1 since the last time you migrated data. These changes are:
>
> Data that customers added via storefront (created orders, reviews,
>   changes in customer profiles, etc.)
>
> All operations with orders, products, and categories in the Magento
>   Admin panel

```
bin/magento migrate:delta -a config.xml
```

Comment: Thanks you. My problem is that I deleted the old m1 database. So there is no way delta can know which changes is recent. Which is also why I'm getting "Deltalog for customer_entity is not installed" error when running it. Am I screwed or is there a way ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think re-migration is a good option, actually, you don't need to re-migrate your data.

There is a more optimal solution is that you can use the **Recent data migration** service or **Smart update** that helps to move newly incurring entities to your new store and bulk update your data on Magento 2.